# ActiveViewModels in Catel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, catel

currently I have a solution with multiple ViewModels - "normal" and "nested" ones.
Every time I create a new ViewModel instance, I can see the new instance in the ViewModelManager.ActiveViewModels. So far so good.
Unfortunately I also can see "old" ViewModel instances there, in fact, instances that are not in use but still remain in this "Cache".
My first question is now, what do I have to do for disposing this "old" ViewModels? 
And an additional question (follow-up)...: which is the recommended usage of ViewModel instantiation to avoid this behavior?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, seems like I found it.
Short description:
Since I cant use the Catel "DataWindow" because we use DevExpress WPF (DXWindow), the ViewModel seems not to be closed automatically on unloading the View.
I fixed the issue by closing the ViewModel myself when the View is unloaded. Snipped:

```
private void OnUnloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
{
  var dc = DataContext as IViewModel;
  if (dc != null && !dc.IsClosed)
    dc.CloseViewModel(null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Catel will automatically close (and remove) the viewmodels as soon as the view models are really out of scope. I recommend that you use the latest prerelease (v.4.0.0) because that is very stable and should solve several issues currently in 3.9.